# Paint.net outline object not working

Tags: object, outline, paint.net

I recently had to replace the hard drive in my computer and re-install Paint.net. I installed the latest version 3.5. When I copied my collection of plugin dll files (including outline Object) the Object option does not show up in the Effects menu. Any advice is appreciated.

Jerry

Answer (score 0):

That's strange.
Have you checked 'Stylize' menu?

If it is not there, please re-install Paint.net, do not copy your plugins, download current release of this plugin from paint.net forum and check again.